# Can we ask questions related to banana pi here?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to ask questions related to banana pi here?

Answer (score 4):

As it stands now the answer is no, however, the topic of extending coverage to include similar boards has been raised before.

Comment: But the Banana Pi it's nearly identical to the Rasp, shouldn't be it allowed, maybe just with a special tag?

Comment: Again not as it stands now. I suggest you read the FAQ. To counter your argument of the similarities take a look at this question http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/26738/56 a Pi does not have a SATA connection for an external hard drive. There are other places both in an outside the Stack Exchange network to ask these questions. The community has intentionally decided not to attempt to be all things to all people.

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Comment: Has this consensus changed meanwhile? [Quoting goldilocks](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33829/kolab-on-the-pi?noredirect=1#comment44283_33829) on my explicit question: *Questions about any model of pi are welcome here*. Of course he could have misunderstood my "BPi" as "RasPi B/B+". Being an SE member for over 3 years now I of course understand there are topics not covered by any SE site, so I won't raise the argument there's no other SE site for that and this being the closest – though architecture and nature of these devices suggest such ;)

Comment: @Izzy No Banana Pi  questions are still off topic. As for where to ask have you tried electrical engineering, or if it deals more with software Unix and Linux might be more appropriate. Without knowing more about the question I can't say where the best place would be

Comment: OK, @SteveRobillard – thanks. I'll check the `/help/on-topic` from time to time in case things change. When I get my current issue solved (see link above), I'll still place an answer as it applies to the ARMv7 RasPis as well – of course in a way it sticks to the rules.

Comment: I run into this same problem when faced with other single-board computers that are ARM, but not under the Raspberry Pi brand (ODroid being another one). Granted, ODroid has their own forums and even subreddit, but good intelligent troubleshooting of any platform-specific problem with it won't find an easy audience on StackExchange at present.

Comment: I think, the platform could easily be identified by tags, in the same way as stackoverflow does with programming languages. Why not extending this platform and maybe renaming it to embedded.stackexchange.com or makers.stackexchange.com? **I see a big demand here**... (i have raspberries and bananas and an arduino)

Comment: @DanielAlder this has been discussed more recently (including a merger with arduino and embedded) . It was not supported and the embedded site proposal failed for a second time. You can view the discussion here http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/567/what-would-you-think-about-broadening-the-topic-to-include-arduino-robotics-and also, note that this was not the first time a merger was proposed either.

Comment: @SteveRobillard good link. Btw I don't care about merging or not. I only want to see a result ;-)

Comment: @DanielAlder if you follow the related links or search for banana Pi you will be able to see that there is no real support for the idea. Our specificity is seen as a benefit. Also, as I said in a recent comment on the issue We (raspberryPi) or SO (stackOverflow) do not need to be all things to all people. http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/611/why-isnt-non-pi-but-pi-like-hardware-supported-here

Comment: @SteveRobillard I wasn't taking only about banana. I care about the current 10-20 known boards on the market and all of those which are coming in the future. But I'm closing here, it's the wrong place for this discussion.

Comment: Has this status changed at all, or are BananaPi's still off-topic here?

Comment: @anonymous2 No it has not.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks!

Comment: Still off-topic in 2019? Where would Banana/Orange/??? Pi questions be welcome? Electrical engineering?

Comment: @AaronF Yes, they are still off-topic. Depending on the question they may be appropriate on EE, StackOverflow, Linux, and Unix among others, however, there may not be a StackExchange site where your question is appropriate. That is one of the things that sets the Raspberry Pi apart. It has a large active and vibrant community while most of the others have sales volumes several orders of magnitude less than the RPi and hence can not support such a community.